# Basic Authentication with multiple request header in HttpwebRequest in c#. Getting error 401 unauthorized

Tags: c#, console-application, webapi

Getting 401 unauthorized error on calling external API from a console application.
through hhtpwebrequest class. Below is my code... requestBody gives me Json data to post

Please suggest to me how to do authentication.

```cs
public string InvokeRestService()
{
    var serviceUrl = "http://xrmd0/api/v1.0/student/specialized/feed";
    var reqData = _service.Retrieve("entityname",
        new Guid("guid"), new ColumnSet("requestdata"));

    var requestBody = reqData.Attributes["requestdata"].ToString();

    string prefix = @"abc""";
    string userName = prefix + "xyz";
    string password = "pwdqawe";

    try
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(serviceUrl));
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        //request.Headers["authorization"] = "Basic" + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password));
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic Auth" + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(userName + ":" + password));
        request.Headers["User-Id"] = "userId";
        request.Headers["User-Type"] = "usertype";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
            var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        var responseString = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseStreamReader.Close();
        return responseString;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: There's no space between the Auth type and the `username:password`

Should look like: `"Authorization": "Basic username:password"` instead of `"Authorization": "Basicusername:password"`

Comment: I also suggest using HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0